# Any idea on how I would refactor this class?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

```
class Die
  def initialize(labels)
     if labels.length < 1
       raise ArgumentError.new('Please put one letter of the alphabet.')
     end

     @labels = labels
  end

  def sides
    @labels.length
  end

  def roll
    @labels.sample
  end
end

p die = Die.new(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

p die.roll
```

Just so all are aware, this code should return the number of sides the die has if you call the sides method. It should return a random side of the die if you call the roll method. If no arguments are passed to the array it should return the customized ArgumentError message.

Comment: What is the goal for your re-factor? If you are looking for general Ruby-ish critique, you may be better off posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. If the API to the class is fixed (which your text suggests is the case), then there is so little code here, there is nothing to do. So most critiques are likely to focus on your choice of public API.

Comment: Yeah, the API to the class is fixed. I just do not have a ton of experience with Ruby so I was wondering if it could be simplified anymore. I felt the same way, there is so little code that there is really nothing else that can be refactored. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you are practising Ruby, the next obvious thing to do is add unit tests (RSpec would be a common and solid choice, other test frameworks are available). If this is implemented from a written spec, check the wording of it carefully to see if stricter validation would help it conform better.

Comment: Looks fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This class should not be refactored. The purpose of refactoring is to keep code clean, readable, efficient, and maintainable. That can mean a lot of things from finding ways to reuse code instead of writing it twice, or to split up methods that are longer than ten lines into multiple smaller methods.

I highly recommend reading the [(unofficial) ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

You'll notice that your class and method names are descriptive of what the object is and what it does, and the methods are all under ten lines. These are good signs that the code doesn't need to be refactored. If anything you might want to change the method name `sides` to `num_sides` to be more descriptive or `@labels` to `@faces`.

EDIT: You can always turn an if statement into one line and will not require an `end`

```
raise ArgumentError.new('Please put one letter of the alphabet.') if labels.length < 1
```

TL;DR This is clean code and doesn't need refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
class Die < Array
  def initialize(labels)
     if labels.length < 1
       raise ArgumentError.new('Please put one letter of the alphabet.')
     end

     super
  end

  alias_method :sides, :length
  alias_method :roll, :sample

end
```

Comment: Neat. Of course you get the rest of `Array` too, including all sorts of non-Die-like behaviour such as `.map!`. There's a close equivalent using `Forwardable` which would demonstrate delegation.

Comment: While this is an awesome example, I disagree with it being a good refactor because as @NeilSlater pointed out, you will add lots of public methods to your `Die` class that you did not intend and can easily be misused.

Comment: I'm not necessarily recommending this refactor here, but it's worth considering - inheriting from core classes is appropriate at times.